# What is the good syntax for acces remote mysql database in persistence.xml?

Tags: mysql, jpa, configuration, persistence, ovh

I have configured my persistence.xml like this :

```
<properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" 
      value="jdbc:mysql://isthmejjozinho.mysql.db/isthmejjozinho" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="myuser" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="mypassword" />
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />  
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
</properties>
```

The console gave me back this error :

> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'isthmejjozinho'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I don't understand why I'm pointing towards localhost whereas I put an existingremote database server adress.

Comment: Looks provider specific, but the error stack trace might help determine why/where the localhost is coming from, such as if a different set of persistence properties is being passed in that overrides your persistence.xml properties

Comment: It was indeed a problem with an override of my persistence.xml.